# Compute $\int_{\gamma} z\, dz$ for any smooth path $\gamma$ which begins at $z_0$ and ends at $w_0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Compute the complex line integral$$\int\limits_{\gamma} z\, \mathrm{d}z$$ for any smooth path $\gamma$ which begins at $z_0$ and ends at $w_0$.

Confused as to how I am supposed to go about parametrizing any smooth path $\gamma$. I know how to solve this for a line from $z_0$ to $w_0$ but I am stumped by "any" smooth path.

Comment: "Any" means you can pick whatever path you like. A straight line from $z_0$ to $w_0$. One that circles around a whole lot. One that starts off in the opposite direction, turns around, and then goes straight to $w_0$. This implies that no matter what path you choose, you'll get the same answer.

Comment: Hint: $z$ is the derivative of $\frac {z^{2}} 2$.

Comment: @ndhanson3 What about $f(z)=z$ makes it so that the integral is independent of path?

Comment: @logitechmouse The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that you learned in calc 1 actually applies to complex functions as well, under some restrictions. Since $f(z)=z$ is defined for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$, the FTC applies. Things get more complicated when you encounter functions like $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ and you have paths around 0.

Comment: Allow $\gamma$ to be an arbitrary continously differentiable curve $\gamma(t) : [a,b] \to \Bbb C : t\mapsto u(t) + iv(t)$. Go to the definition of the path integral to convert $\int_\gamma z\,dz$ to a sum of integrals $\int_a^b \phi_1(t)\,dt + i\int_a^b \phi_2(t)\,dt$ where $\phi_1, \phi_2$ are the functions (in terms of $u, v$) you get from the definition. Discover that by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the values of these integrals will depend only on $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$, independent of how $\gamma$ gets from one to the other.

Comment: Lastly, note that this only worked because $z$ is the derivative of another function, as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out. "Defined everywhere" is not enough to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=z$ is an *entire* function in the complex plane, so $\int_\gamma z\,dz$ only depends on the endpoints of $\gamma$ and not the "interior" of it (like a conservative vector field). The result for any path from $z_0$ to $w_0$ is the same as the result for the straight line from $z_0$ to $w_0$: $\frac12(w_0^2-z_0^2)$.